# Why I can use `ng-bind` outside of `ng-app`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind, ng-app

Why I can use `ng-bind` outside of `ng-app` and `ng-controller` when using `$rootScope.variable`?

```
faraWorkspaceApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (e, toState, toParams
                                                   , fromState, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.pageTitle = toState.pageTitle;
    });
});

<span ng-bind="pageTitle"></span>
<div ng-app>
</div>
```

Comment: could you reproduce the problem with plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: ng-app is the directive for root element. Angularjs will only process element in ng-app

Comment: I think you should put ng-app on <html> tag as it will allow you to use angular js framework for entire app. It is not possible to use a component outside its framework bounds. $rootScope allows you to use a variable in all controllers, services, factories, filters and configs but that doesn't mean you can use it outside bound of a framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scopes are tied to an controller, without the controller they can't be put into your view.  $rootScope is tied to your ng-app, so in actual fact you can't use it outside of ng-app but you can use it outside of ng-controller.

$scopes have an inheritance model, which means child $scopes will automatically get the value of the parent $scope.